# Cordova iOS no longer loading three.js .glb files

Tags: ios, cordova, three.js

I have a Cordova app (built with react) which renders 3d (.glb) models on my iPhone (using three.js).

It's old, and used Cordova's iOS@5 platform.  I updated it to Cordova's newer ios@6 platform, and the .glb files no longer load on the iPhone.

They load fine locally, when run in the browser. but they do not load in the iPhone.  If I use the older ios 5, it works fine.

Is there a known reason three.js no longer works in ios6?  a plugin that needs to be added?  a build setting that must now be added that didn't before?

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably because you were running UIWebView which has been deprecated. Now WKVebView does not allow to load files like UIWebView used to.

You could give a try to this plugin https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr and then set your preferences to

```
 <preference name="AllowUntrustedCerts"  value="true" />
 <preference name="InterceptRemoteRequests" value="all" />
 <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

Note that this is for iOS 6+

Comment: This fixed it for me!  I love you.  You are the wind beneath my wings.

Comment: Wow thanks for the kind words! Happy coding!